# In ramda.js, does fromPairs change the order of elements?

Tags: ramda.js

I receive large array of pairs:`[number, {number,number, big array of numbers}]`

First I add my main pair to beginning of the array:

```
prepend([target[0], {count : target[1].length, overall : target[1].length, items:target[1]}]),
```

Next I do:

```
  Promise.all([                                        
          to_file_json(
          token.user_id,
          'connections_data',
          JSON.stringify(
          fromPairs(r[0])
          ))...
```

And I can find my main pair somewhere in the middle of my file.

So my question is, could `fromPairs` possibly change the order? If yes what can I do to prevent this?

Edit:

additional info:

1)`r` variable correspond to `[[number, Friends][], Float64Array[]]`

2) `target` variable correspond to `[number,number[]]`

3) Beginning of element which i'm prepend, it's always the biggest one, and it got in the middle of the file somehow.

```
"136444868":{"count":304,"overall":304,"items":[19363,234566,290677,1375661,2030175,2131497,2593602,2596894,2816890,2869895,3170377,3437884,3486703,3504543,4046799,4235623,5366101.....
```

4) Friends type :

```
interface Friends {
    count:number,   
    overall:number,
    items:number[]  
   };
```

sample data

```
{
    "19363":{"count":5,"overall":3088,"items":[51177198,53119509,136035431,209482119,216378147]}

    ,"234566":{"count":6,"overall":6803,"items":[290677,3504543,23180680,75311610,178479726,196401211]}

    ,"290677":{"count":19,"overall":2213,"items":[234566,5686439,7873089,11175816,13726459,20697213,23180680,27419631,55209039,74493674,75311610,125041200,133272552,139307068,159591583,168386810,173599247,178429642,189097165]}


    ,"1375661":{"count":0,"overall":76,"items":[]},"2030175":{"count":14,"overall":86,"items":[2596894,6507568,11681736,17736119,49557638,117771194,127144880,141523415,147264238,153044182,156925389,160656334,223530741,262311445]},"2131497":{"count":16,"overall":301,"items":[13598979,15682478,20357560,20869716,27419631,30869837,33650605,40129023,68976427,88146695,90648231,101105191,118193129,145163503,216503667,387266562]},
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sure one moment

Comment: Note that Ramda thinks of objects as unordered collections.  But, assuming that the underlying engine doesn't reorder things, the object will likely have keys that iterate in the same order they're added.  This means that `fromPairs` and `toPairs` should act like inverses.  Ramda itself does not enforce this, though.

Comment: Okey i see, thank you for response

Comment: With some data, perhaps someone here can figure out what's wrong, though.

Comment: And how does that data correspond to `target` and `r`?

Comment: I added additional info, but this is not a serious problem, i just thought it resorts data in some way deliberately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect the issue is that you do a `prepend` without removing the element from its later place in the list.

Then you might end up with some data like:

```
[
  [ 2131497, { count: 16, overall: 301, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],  // duplicate
  [ 19363, { count: 5, overall: 3088, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],
  [ 234566, { count: 6, overall: 6803, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],
  [ 290677, { count: 19, overall: 2213, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],
  [ 1375661, { count: 0, overall: 76, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],
  [ 2030175, { count: 14, overall: 86, items: [ /* .. * ] } ],
  [ 2131497, { count: 16, overall: 301, items: [ /* .. * ] } ]   // duplicate
]
```

Then, when you do [`fromPairs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#fromPairs), the later version will override the earlier one, and it will end up back in the list at the original position, as per this line from the documentation:

> If a key appears in multiple pairs, the rightmost pair is included in the object.

But... even if you fix this, you will still not get the behavior you want, because of the object property [iteration order specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys), which says that integer keys of an object are iterated first, in numeric order, before the non-integer keys. Axel Rauschmayer has a very [readable description](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html) of this.

These complexities are one of the reasons that Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) has not created a `foldObj` implementation.